Trying to update table using PreparadStatement, But parameters are generated inside a Parentheses
Using JDBC connection in Java framework, Am updating column values my lfvadd table.
this is my sample code :
PreparedStatement pst = null;
String sql = ("UPDATE lfvadd  SET recipe_name = ? WHERE recipe_id = ?");
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
          
pst.setString(1,"malgapodi coconut tomato");
pst.setString(2, "40892");
System.out.println(pst);
pst.executeUpdate(sql);

Actual output : UPDATE lfvadd  SET recipe_name = ('malgapodi coconut tomato') WHERE recipe_url = ('40892')
expected output is : UPDATE lfvadd  SET recipe_name = 'malgapodi coconut tomato' WHERE recipe_url = '40892'

Just an observation: These extra parentheses are added (for example) by the Postgres JDBC driver, but not (for example) by the MySQL driver - so it can depend on which database driver you are using - and maybe also the driver version. Different drivers may also format the output in other different ways. For example, MySQL adds com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement:  to the string printed by System.out.println(pst);.

If you are using this output for any type of unit testing ("actual output" vs. "expected output"), I would suggest you don't do that. You cannot rely on how each driver vendor has chosen to implement the toString method of pst. They will not be consistent across different JDBC drivers.

Why does it matter if the parentheses are there?
